# Issue with managing branches and cherry-picking commits

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have the following branch structure in git, with a master, where I have frozen the code and only important fixes are being made to a hotfix branch.
I am cherry picking changes from hotfix branch,not necessarily in chronological order.
But I want that the hotfix branch should have all the changes from master. (Because I made some changes which necessarily have to go into the release by passing hotfix workflow.)
It is acceptable that the hotfix branch is going to be discarded in a few days.

But when I rebase hotfix to master, after cherrypicking the changes, will I see 2 commits w.r.t the commit-b which I picked up from earlier? Diagram below.

My second issue is, is this the right branching strategy? And is there something better? 
[image]

Comment: Is this not a valid question? Why the negative rating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rebase `hotfix` onto `master`, you will indeed see 2 "b" commits; the cherry-picked one, and the rebased one.

I would suggest that instead of your current process, you create one `hotfix/XXX` branch per fix you want in `master`, so that you can merge that entire branch into `master`, i.e. no cherry picking necessary.

Comment: My intention is never to merge hotfix onto master, but only rebase master on hotfix. Also, as SCM will it not be very cumbersome for me to manage hotfix/XXX as a strategy.

Comment: I generally would merge instead of rebase in this case, so that you can also merge the hotfix into your develop branch. And I don't think having a branch per hotfix is particularly cumbersome; it is just one additional git command. I would take a look at git flow: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/